# Why JavaScript has following kind of wired behaviour?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I was trying something in the browser console and I encountered the following scenario. What is happening under the hood here?

```
'hello'[4] === 'hello'[1,2,3,4] === true;
```

Comment: `'hello'[4]` gives `o` as does `'hello'[1,2,3,4]`. Why `'hello'[1,2,3,4]` returns 'o' though is probably your real question

Answer (score -2):

Because both `'hello'[4]` and `'hello'[1,2,3,4]` returns `o`

Comment: why does `'hello'[1,2,3,4]` return `o` though?

Comment: It takes the last index value `4` and becomes similar to `'hello'[4]`. Hence, `'hello'[1,2]` returns `l`